# Magento 2: How to add multiple select dropdown field in my existing module with store database

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I have create online module by "https://code.vky.co.in/magento-2-module-creator/" this site.
Now i want to add extra custom filed of multiple select dropdown.
Dropdown filed showing lavel is product name and value is product id.
How to get product name and id in dropdown with store value in database
How to do?
please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achive via renderer. do something like below example

You can add Renderer in your **Form.php** file like this.

```
$fieldset->addType(
    'club_color',
    'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Color'
);

$field = $fieldset->addField(
    'club_color',
    'club_color',
    [
        'name' => 'club_color',
        'label' => __('Color'),
        'title' => __('Color')
    ]
);
```

And now you need to create your renderer file here in your module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Color.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer;

class Color extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getElementHtml();
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $el = $("#' . $this->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!